# Graph Ramsey number $R(3;5) > 10$

Tags: ramsey-theory

Show that there is a way to color $K_{10}$ graph's edges in a way that it won't have a sub-graph $K_3$ that its edges are
red and it won't have a sub-graph $K_5$ that its edges are blue.

What would you do?
[image: K-10]

Thanks in advance!

My thoughts: color every couple that are next to each other in a different color that makes sure I won't have a sub-graph K-3 but it's hard for me to see if I fulfill the other term as well because the drawing is very crowded and hard for me to visualize

Comment: Use 10 different colors? :D just joking, try to give us some of your thoughts, this helps people to see where you are stuck.

Comment: @Student just did :) Can you help?  :)

Comment: I am not really familiar with graph theory, I was just curious because of your title (sorry). Anyway, I suppose you can only use two colors?

Comment: @Student you're right. otherwise I would have just picked green and color all

Comment: Just to clarify, you want us to colour the edges of $K_{10}$ in red & blue, so the red edges avoid $K_3$ and the blue edges avoid $K_5$ ... right ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $K_5$ has lots of edges, so we just need to turn a few edges red to eliminate them.  The trick is doing so without forming a red triangle, which is a $K_3$.  Start with the whole graph colored blue.  Number the vertices $0$ to $9$ around the circle.  Color all the outside edges red, so $i(i+1)$ and $90$. This breaks all the $K_5$s except $02468$ and $13579.$  Now color $26$ and $37$ red which breaks those two.  There are still no red triangles.